# Unable to replace using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, regexp-replace

I am trying to replace a particular set of strings using RegExp but it is not replacing. The regex I am trying is

```
\@223(?:\D|'')\gm
```

The set of strings to test on are these

```
@223 ->Replace 223 with #
@223+@33 ->Replace 223 with #
@22;    ->Not Replace
@2234   ->Not Replace 
@22234  ->Not Replace
@223@44  ->Replace 223 with #
```

Comment: do you went to change it to `223 with #` if it start with `@223` ?

Comment: do you want replace ```233``` by ```#``` ?

Comment: Just use `str = str.replace(/@223\b/, "#")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this what you went :

```
var string = `
@223
@223+@33
@22;
@2234
@22234
@223@44
`;
regex = /(?<=@)(223)(?=\D)/g;
string = string.replace(regex, "#");
console.log(string);
```

output :

```
@#
@#+@33
@22;
@2234
@22234
@#@44
```

explanation :

```
(?<=@) : test if leaded by @ character.
(?=\D) : followed by any character except digit
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your regex:

1. You're using the wrong slashes, should be `/@223(?:\D|'')/gm`.
2. The non-capturing group will still be included in the complete match, so you might need to add parenthesis around just the `@223` part and just replace that group.

You can test your regex in a service like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/). Note that in that service, the start and end slashes are already implicitly included.